# How Codility calculates the complexity? Example: Tape-Equilibrium Codility Training

Tags: time-complexity

I was training in Codility solving the first lesson: [`Tape-Equilibrium`](https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/tape_equilibrium).

It is said it has to be of complexity O(N). Therefore I was trying to solve the problem with just one `for`. I knew how to do it with two `for` but I understood it would have implied a complexity of O(2N), therefore I skipped those solutions.

I looked for it in Internet and of course, [in SO there was an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455058/tape-equilibrium-codility-training)

To my astonishment, all the solutions first calculate the sum of the elements of the vector and afterwards make the calculations. I understand this is complexity O(2N), but it gets an score of 100%.

At this point, I think I am mistaken about my comprehension of the time complexity limits. If they ask you to get a time complexity of O(N), is it right to get O(X*N)? Being X a value not really high ?

How does this works?

Comment: This might be better in the CSTheory stack. // I think that as long as the X << N then it is ignored, in general; Big-O notation excludes coefficients and low order terms. So O(XN) = O(N) // This makes sense because if you think about it 2N to N is nothing compared to N^2 to N when dealing with sufficiently large N.

Comment: The explanation above is a bit misleading. If K is a constant then O(KN) = O(N). This is true regardless of how big K is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `f` and `g` be functions.
The Big-O notation `f in O(g)` means that you can find a constant number `c` such that `f(n) ≤ c⋅g(n)`. So if your algorithm has complexity `2N` (or `XN` for a constant `X`) this is in `O(N)` due to `c = 2` (or `c = X`) holds `2N ≤ c⋅N = 2⋅N` (or `XN ≤ c⋅N = X⋅N`).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to keep it O(N) along with a 100% score:

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can use System.out.println for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int[] s1 = new int[A.length-1];
        int[] s2 = new int[A.length-1];
        for(int i=0;i<A.length-1;i++){
            if(i>0){
                s1[i] = s1[i-1] + A[i];
            }
            else {
                 s1[i] = A[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i=A.length-1;i>0;i--){
            if(i<A.length-1){
                s2[i-1] = s2[i] + A[i];
            }
            else {
                s2[i-1] = A[A.length-1];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<A.length-1;i++){
            if(Math.abs(s1[i]-s2[i])<result){
                result = Math.abs(s1[i]-s2[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```